# @echo off in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, echo

I'm trying to write a BAT script and I have the following:

```
@echo off
REM Comments here
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set PROG_ROOT=C:\Prog
set ONE=1

echo 1>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
echo %ONE%>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (folders.txt) do (
    echo %%f>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
)

ENDLOCAL
```

My folders.txt contains the number "5".

My test.txt output is

```
ECHO is off
ECHO is off
5
```

I don't understand why the first 2 lines of output has "ECHO is off", while the third line is printed out correctly. How do I print the correct output?

ETA: I tried

```
echo 1>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
echo %ONE% >> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
```

and I was able to print

```
ECHO is off
1
```

However, I need to NOT print the trailing space after the number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1>` (and more generally `n>` for any digit `n`) is interpreted as a redirection, and thus `echo 1>>` appears to `cmd` as an `echo` with no arguments. `echo` with no arguments will print the current `echo` state (here, `ECHO is off`).

To fix, escape the integer with a `^` character:

```
echo ^1>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
```

Comment: Or move the redirection to the front: `>>%PROG_ROOT%\test.txt echo %ONE%`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
echo %ONE%>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (folders.txt) do (
    echo %%f>> %PROG_ROOT\test.txt
)

ENDLOCAL
```