# Writing single digit numbers to a text file

Tags: batch-file

I have this code

```
rem Saved in D:\Temp\WriteText.bat
@echo off
@echo -ATTEDIT> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo y>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo 36x24bdr>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo SUBTITLE>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo B209 11.5 TON BRIDGE ELEC LAYOUT 1 ^& 2>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo 612.9014,43.8533>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo 618.5063,35.8628>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo 109.9409,-6.7209>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo.>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo v>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo c>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo B209>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo B211>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt
@echo Next>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt

pause
```

that creates a text file and fills it with text. The problem is that  the line that is intended to write the text "B209 11.5 TON BRIDGE ELEC LAYOUT 1 & 2" is not writing. Instead, it gets fed back on to the screen.

*see link for screenshot*
http://gyazo.com/a97e6daaf4695b766659df426180c95b

We troubleshooted the problem as much as we could and found that t**his only happens when the number is single digit and both preceded and followed by only a space**.

**For example:**

- "1a" will work
- "11" will work
- "1." will work
- " 1 " will *not* work

It is a requirement for the text read as " 1 & 2" verbatim. What can we do to achieve this?

Comment: Please reduce the pasted code to a minimum needed to reproduce the problem. In your case, that's one line only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of specifying where each echo should go on every line
(i.e `@echo -ATTEDIT> ATTEDITChangeName.txt`) , use this method of block form. It will solve the issue you've been having and clean up your code a bit.

```
@echo off

> ATTEDITChangeName.txt (
@echo -ATTEDIT
@echo y
@echo 36x24bdr
@echo SUBTITLE
@echo B209 11.5 TON BRIDGE ELEC LAYOUT 1 ^& 2
@echo 612.9014,43.8533
@echo 618.5063,35.8628
@echo 109.9409,-6.7209
@echo.
@echo v
@echo c
@echo B209
@echo B211
@echo Next
)    
pause
```

Using `> ATTEDITChangeName.txt` (as i did in my example) will override the current contents of the file, and replace it with what is in the (). If you wish to simple add text to the file, use `>> ATTEDITChangeName.txt`.

While i'm unsure why this issue arises, the above code format will solve your problem and print all of the text to the text file.

Comment: So I did a bit of diving around the web and find out why it did what it did. While I do not understand it,

@echo B209 11.5 TON BRIDGE ELEC LAYOUT 1 ^& ^2>>ATTEDITChangeName.txt 

works. Just a heads up for someone else having a similar problem down the road.

Also, thanks for cleaning p my code a bit! Once I get it working, I hardly every go back and clean it up

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that. However, your answer does not explain what's wrong with OP's code.

Comment: If you look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505754/echo-off-in-dos-cmd I believe they got closer to answering it than we ever will, and I still don't understand it

Answer (score 0):

The term `2>>` means that Windows will redirect StdErr output. To avoid that, move the redirection `>>` to the front of the command like this:

```
echo>>ATTEDITChangeName.txt B209 11.5 TON BRIDGE ELEC LAYOUT 1 ^& 2
```

I agree, it looks a bit strange when you first use it that way, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. Looks as though there were more than one work around. As mentioned above in my comment putting a carrot in front of the 2 also works as a solution.